# What would be the better way of getting linked models values from db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

First of all, I'm very new to the ASP.NET MVC C# and EF. I'm in a process of creating a website that should hopefully help me learn these three wonderful technologies. with that said, I have the following models in my project.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    //public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool? ChangePassword { get; set; }
    public bool? Deletable { get; set; }

    //Add more Properties for more fields

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyInformation> ParentCompanies { get; set; }
    public virtual StaffProfile sProfile { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class StaffProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StaffProfileId { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public StaffGrouping Group { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public bool isPhoneNumberDisplayed { get; set; }
    public bool TextNotificationsAllowed { get; set; }
    public bool EmailNotificationsAllowed { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNotificationsAllowed { get; set; }
}
```

Staff Grouping

```
public class StaffGrouping
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

and just for completeness, the phone numbers model

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public PhoneType Type { get; set; }
    public bool isPrimary { get; set; }
    public bool isInActive { get; set; }
}

public enum PhoneType { 
    Home,
    Mobile,
    Work,
    Other
    }
```

I'm trying to get all the staffs from the db (including the phone numbers, userprofile and group they are linked to) and adding it to a viewmodel for better integration with my view. currently I'm doing it as such:

public ActionResult ManageStaff()
        {
            using (var repo = new CompanyInformationRepository(new UniteOfWorkCompanies()))
            {
                var company = repo.FindCompany(User.Identity.Name);

```
            var Users = repo.CompanyStafflookup(company);

            var model = new List<StaffManagementViewModel>();

            foreach (var user in Users)
            {
                var group = repo.StaffGroupLookup(user.sProfile);


                //var phoneNumber = user.sProfile.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.isPrimary == true).FirstOrDefault();

                model.Add(new StaffManagementViewModel
                {
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.Lastname,
                    EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress,
                    PhoneNumber = "(915) 433 - 1739", //phoneNumber.Number,
                    Group = group.GroupName,
                    UserID = user.UserId
                });
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

And my repository:

```
    public IQueryable<HoursOfOperation> CompanyHoursLookup(string userName)
    {
        var company = FindCompany(userName).id;

        //var model = _db.HoursOfOperations.Where(e => e.Company.id == company);

        var model = from h in _db.HoursOfOperations
                    where h.Company.id == company
                    orderby h.Day ascending, h.From ascending
                    select h;


        return model;
    }

    public IQueryable<UserProfile> CompanyStafflookup(CompanyInformation company)
    {

        var model = from s in _db.UserProfiles.Include("sProfile")
                    where s.ParentCompanies.Any(e => e.companyName == company.companyName)
                    orderby s.FirstName ascending
                    select s;

        return model;
    }

    public StaffGrouping StaffGroupLookup(StaffProfile Staff)
    {
        var Staffwithgroup = _db.StaffProfiles.Where(e => e.StaffProfileId == Staff.StaffProfileId).Include("Group").FirstOrDefault();

        return Staffwithgroup.Group;
    }
```

I'm guessing there should be a better more efficient way of doing this as I'm counting at least three trips to the database. I tried to use the `.include` but on the `userprofile` but since I don't have a navigation Property to point at the group, its giving me an error. the code I'm talking about is the following:

```
        var model = from s in _db.UserProfiles.Include("sProfile").Include("PhoneNumbers").Include("Group")
                    where s.ParentCompanies.Any(e => e.companyName == company.companyName)
                    orderby s.FirstName ascending
                    select s;
```

Is there a way to achieve this in one call that basically would return a list of `UserProfiles` that includes the `StaffProfile` that includes the `PhoneNumbers` and finally the `Group`?

Comment: Afaik you can simply prefix the include with the full path, i.e. use `Include("sProfile.Group")` to include both StaffProfile and it's Group.

Comment: @MortenMertner Thank you so much, I thought there has to be a way to do this but just didn't know that you can put the full path on here. Like I said, I am very new to the whole asp.net mvc and am learning one step at a time. Would you mind submitting this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply prefix the include with the full path, i.e. use:

```
Include("sProfile.Group")
```

This will include both StaffProfile and it's Group.